# How do I check whether a node is flagged when it is being deleted?

Tags: hooks, flags

I'm using the Flags module for some functionality on my site. When a node is deleted, I need to check whether it's flagged or not and take additional action based on that. I've implemented `hook_nodeapi()` in my module to add my logic when a node is deleted. However, it seems I'm unable to check whether the node is flagged or not... I always get `FALSE` when I check, even when I know that node was in fact flagged. My code so far is:

```
// check if this node is flagged for renewal
$flag = flag_get_flag('machine_name_of_my_flag');

if($flag && $flag->is_flagged($node->nid)) {
   // add my custom logic here
}
```

This code is definitely run when the node is deleted. The `$flag` is found correctly, but `$flag->is_flagged($node->nide)` always returns false. I based this code on the documentation for the [Flag API](http://drupal.org/node/305086). I'm not sure why the `is_flagged` check is always returning false. Is it something to do with the delete action? When I debug this code in xDebug, I can see all the properties of the node object, but I can't find out if it's flagged or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code works, but if the module that implements `hook_nodeapi()` is executed before Flag; differently, it will be executed after [flag_nodeapi()](http://drupalcode.org/project/flag.git/blob/refs/heads/6.x-2.x:/flag.module#l446), which removes any reference to the deleted node from the database tables used by Flag.

```
case 'delete':
  foreach (flag_get_flags('node') as $flag) {
    // If the flag is being tracked by translation set and the node is part
    // of a translation set, don't delete the flagging record.
    // Instead, data will be updated in the 'translation_change' op, below.
    if (!$flag->i18n || empty($node->tnid)) {
      db_query("DELETE FROM {flag_content} WHERE fid = %d AND content_id = %d", $flag->fid, $node->nid);
      db_query("DELETE FROM {flag_counts} WHERE fid = %d AND content_id = %d", $flag->fid, $node->nid);
    }
  }
  break;
```

If the short name of the module starts with any letter after the *f*, then that module needs to change its weight to a number lower than 0; it is usually done in the implementation of [hook_install()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--install.php/function/hook_install/6), or [hook_update_N()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--install.php/function/hook_update_N/6).

```
db_query("UPDATE {system} SET weight = %d WHERE name = 'mymodule' AND type = 'module', -1);
```